# How to realize a Minimap / Mapcontrol using Bitmap and WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, dictionary

As the title is already describing I am working on a custom standalone minimap application for a game. It should also have the possibility to place custom markers. This feature does not have to be interactive, it could also load fixed markers from the code or a file.

I am looking for some advice on the best approach, it does not have to be something real fancy. It is only for personal use. Only one thing is fixed: The worldmap is supplied as *.bmp.
I am also aiming for writing everything myself (so not using any Nugets) for the sake of learning.

Below you will find my current approach. This is the first version, so the code is far from being optimized...

MainWindow.xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer x:Name="MyScrollViewer" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Visible">
    <Image x:Name="WorldMap" Source="..." Stretch="None"/>
</ScrollViewer>
<Rectangle Name="Player" RadiusX="3" RadiusY="3" Height="6" Width="6" Fill="White"/>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        Demo();
    }

    private async void Demo()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            var result = GameClient.GetPlayerPosition();

            var hori = result[0] - MyScrollViewer.ActualWidth / 2;
            var verti = result[1] - MyScrollViewer.ActualHeight / 2;

            MyScrollViewer.ScrollToHorizontalOffset(hori);
            MyScrollViewer.ScrollToVerticalOffset(verti);

            await Task.Delay(100);
        }
    }
```

My first goal was to be able to track the clients position at all, which worked.
The map is moving accordingly as long as the player is not near the edges of the map.
If the player is near any edge, the app is not tracking the position correctly, since the ScrollViewer can not scroll below zero. But I am aware of this.

The next step would be to also move the Player-Rectangle I defined in the XAML, to be able to track its position near the edges. This is something I am currently not worried about.

So I basically have two questions:

1. Do you think the current approach is fine?
2. How could I realize custom markers / labels on the map?

Edit:
This is the final solution after Clemens suggested it in the comments:

XAML:

```
    <Grid Background="Black">
        <Canvas x:Name="MainCanvas">
            <Image x:Name="WorldMapRot" Source="..." Stretch="None"/>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

Codebehind:

```
    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonDown(e);
        CaptureMouse();
        start = e.GetPosition(this);
        origin.X = MainCanvas.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetX;
        origin.Y = MainCanvas.RenderTransform.Value.OffsetY;
        isDragged = true;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseLeftButtonUp(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseLeftButtonUp(e);
        ReleaseMouseCapture();
        isDragged = false;
    }

    protected override void OnMouseMove(MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isDragged == false)
            return;

        base.OnMouseMove(e);
        if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed && IsMouseCaptured)
        {
            var pos = e.GetPosition(this);
            var matrix = MainCanvas.RenderTransform.Value;
            matrix.OffsetX = origin.X + (pos.X - start.X);
            matrix.OffsetY = origin.Y + (pos.Y - start.Y);

            MainCanvas.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(matrix);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnMouseWheel(MouseWheelEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseWheel(e);
        Point p = e.MouseDevice.GetPosition(MainCanvas);
        Matrix m = MainCanvas.RenderTransform.Value;

        if (e.Delta > 0)
            m.ScaleAtPrepend(1.1, 1.1, p.X, p.Y);
        else
            m.ScaleAtPrepend(1 / 1.1, 1 / 1.1, p.X, p.Y);

        MainCanvas.RenderTransform = new MatrixTransform(m);
    }
```

Comment: Not sure if a ScrollViewer with Scrollbars is desirable. I would probably put the Image element, the player Rectangle and any marker elements in a Canvas, where you could set absolute positions via the Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top properties. Then make the whole Canvas pannable by a TranslateTransform in its RenderTransform. Or pannable and zoomable by a MatrixTransform.

Comment: Very good call! I did not know how to handle a Canvas in WPF, never done something like this before. Works like a charm, also the issue with the player being too close to the edge of the world is solved that way. I will implement pan and will post the result here.